# From request import PandaRequest ImportError: No module named 'request'

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, request, package

I am trying to use panda. When I import it as

```
import panda as pd
```

I get this error

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/panda/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from request import PandaRequest ImportError: No module named 'request'
```

'request' seems to be already installed:

```
  Requirement already satisfied: request in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
```

I am using Python 3.5. I read around and the problem appears to exist only with 2.7. Do you have an idea of why it does not work?

Thanks

Bruno

Comment: Don't you mean to have installed and used module ["pandas"](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas) instead of [panda](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/panda)? (AFAIK the error you see is because panda doesn't support python 3)

Comment: Try to change `panda` to `pandas`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think you mean the pandas library, in which case you use

```
import pandas as pd
```

Answer (score 14):

Indeed its confusing when there are 2 libraries with similar name like panda and pandas.

- Panda is a cloud-based platform that provides video and audio encoding infrastructure, and as error suggests, it looks for request module.
- Pandas provides easy-to-use data structures and data analysis tools.

Answer (score 7):

**use this:**

```
pip install pandas
```

**now import:**

```
import pandas as pd
```