# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'request' in Python

Tags: python, module, pip

I was trying to install a module named `panda`, to clarify, I actually want to use the `panda` package instead of `pandas`. I installed it using `pip install panda`, and `cmd` displayed *requirement already satisfied*. Normally, I could use this module by using this code:

```py
import panda
```

But when I typed in this line of code, python gave me this error that did not make any sense:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\xyccx_mdrrjg8\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\panda\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from request import PandaRequest
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'request'
```

I was importing `panda`, and it said that `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'request'`. There is no connection between this error message and the code that I wrote. How should I fix this bug?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From request import PandaRequest ImportError: No module named 'request'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351534/from-request-import-pandarequest-importerror-no-module-named-request)

Comment: I really want to import module `panda`, not `pandas`.

Comment: It looks like the panda package either misses a dependency, has a mistake (request might be requests), or is simply broken. Could you point people to which panda package you installed? The only panda package I can find that is just named `panda` is from 2015, i.e., a seven year old package, with no documentation (and very unlikely to work with Python 3.10)

Comment: Is  panda really a module?? are you sure its not pandas or something.

Comment: @Naman Yes, it is.

Comment: please can you send its pypi package link i will look into its dependencies and then can help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this library suffers from relative import errors, which is weird for such a popular library.

To fix it, go to the `python/site-packages/panda` directory, in your case, it is `C:\Users\xyccx_mdrrjg8\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\panda\`.

In the `__init__.py`, change the first 5 lines to:

```py
from . request import PandaRequest
from . models import Video, Cloud, Encoding, Profile, Notifications, PandaDict
from . models import GroupRetriever, SingleRetriever
from . models import PandaError
from . upload_session import UploadSession
```

In `upload_session.py`, change the third line to:

```py
from . models import Video
```